# how to check function is called or not after http post call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my one function in which there is a `http` post request ,after success it call a function I want to check it `function is called or not after success`.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-currying-5q1b8
**I am testing below function**

```
export const saveWithoutSubmit = async (values, updateTaskListAfterFilter) => {
  var obj = {
    remarks: values.remarks,
    requestedBy: localStorage.getItem("msisdn")
  };
  try {
    const response = await sendPostRequest(`${API_TASK_URL}closeSr`, {
      ...obj,
      saveWithoutSubmit: true
    });

    if (response && response.data && response.data.status.code !== "200") {
      error(response.data.result.message);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
      success(response.data.status.message);
      updateTaskListAfterFilter();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response && e.response.data) {
      console.log(e.response.data.message);
      error(e.response.data.status.message);
    }
  }
};
```

I am doing testing like this

```
describe("remark service test", () => {
  const fakeAxios = {
    post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { greeting: "hello there" } }))
  };

  const sendPostRequest = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ data: { greeting: "hello there" } })
  );
  it("save without sumit", async done => {
    const mockUpdateTaskListAfterFilter = jest.fn();
    const updateTaskListAfterFilter = () => {};
    saveWithoutSubmit({}, mockUpdateTaskListAfterFilter);

    // expect(updateTaskListAfterFilter).toBeCalled();
    expect(mockUpdateTaskListAfterFilter).toBeCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

**getting error**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting your question multiple times and instead fix the original question. This kind of behaviour will only result in a ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put a variable in the normal arrow function and await saveWithoutSubmit

**remark.service.js**

```js
const sendPostRequest = () => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    data: {
      greeting: "hello there",
      status: {
        code: "200"
      }
    }
  });
};

export const saveWithoutSubmit = async(values, updateTaskListAfterFilter) => {
  try {
    const response = await sendPostRequest();
    if (response && response.data && response.data.status.code !== "200") {
      console.log("Error");
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Sucess");
      updateTaskListAfterFilter();
      return;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response && e.response.data) {
      console.log(e.response.data.message);
    }
  }
};
```

**remark.service.test.js**

```js
import {
  saveWithoutSubmit
} from "./remark.service";

describe("remark service test", () => {
  it("save without sumit", async function() {
    console.log("save without sumit getting called");
    let called = false;
    const mockUpdateTaskListAfterFilter = () => {
      console.log("callback");
      called = true;
    };

    await saveWithoutSubmit({}, mockUpdateTaskListAfterFilter);
    console.log("after saveWithoutSubmit", called);
    expect(called).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-currying-5q1b8 not working...!! still fail

Comment: please remove this answer

Comment: Using a fake `sendPostRequest` as I do not know whats happening on your api. https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-kilby-zdz7y

Comment: how to make `fake` sendPostrequest

Comment: it just returns a promise the resolved to example data. This can imitate the request for reproducibility.

Comment: but `you make fake request in my service but in actual it is calling to api `

Comment: can we make `this fake request in my test` something mook `http request` ..any idea ..in other words call post request `/api` with some data `{a:abc}`  (`example`).same request I will mook in my test

Comment: in my example `saveWithoutSubmit` I am hitting to a server a post request (to get data.) but i while doing testing we are not hitting to actual url to we to mook my http request ..can we do that ?

Comment: As this test is validating the implementation of `saveWithoutSubmit`. It makes it easier to remove external dependencies, like an API. That way, if you want to make a test for when the responce has a `status.code !== 200`, you can easily just change the fake `sendPostrequest` to send a different response, instead of changing your api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207930/discussion-between-user944513-and-jacob).

Comment: For example, if something where to go wrong with your api, it would make your `saveWithoutSubmit` tests fail, even through nothing has changed. The API endpoints should all be under their own tests